Trivial normal bundle of area minimizing two-sphere
In "RIGIDITY OF AREA-MINIMIZING TWO-SPHERES IN THREE-MANIFOLDS" by Bray, Brendle, Neves
they consider the case of area-minimizing two spheres on a compact three manifold with positive scalar curvature and $\pi_2(M) \neq 0$. Let $f:S^2 \to M$ be a non-trivial element of $\pi_2(M)$. Why is the normal bundle of this immersion trivial?

What is the rank of the normal bundle? What do you know about such bundles over $S^2$?

The rank is one and for the standard embedding of $S^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ the normal bundle is trivial. But why is this also true for some immersion as above?

I claim that every real line bundle over $S^2$ is trivial. How you see this depends on what you know. Are you familiar with covering spaces?
